# How can I identify the role of an infinitive in a sentence?

Tags: nouns, adverbs, infinitives, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

Infinitives may function as nouns, adjectives or adverbs. Since infinitives are derived from verbs, they do express actions or states of being.

However, there is some difficulty in identifying the particular ***role*** of the infinitive in a sentence. Is there a generic test available to determine whether each infinitive is serving as a noun, adjective, or adverb?

I will be taking the GMAT exam shortly, and this is an area that I am particularly weak in. It is necessary to identify the role of Infinitives in order to get answers right for questions related to Parallelism and Verb Tense.

**Example:** 
"Half our life is spent trying to find something to do with the time we have rushed through life trying to save." - Will Rogers

Comment: There are very few "generic tests" that apply to sentences. There are a number of characteristics that contribute to uses, but the most important one, since infinitives and gerunds are always subordinate constructions, is the main predicate in the clause they modify, which may be a verb, a noun, or an adjective (or adverb, for that matter). The commanding predicate determines whether there can be any subordinate clause at all; whether it can be an infinitive, or a gerund, or any other kind of subordinate clause; and which specific senses each such clause can have.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this. Isn't the pattern 'to (verb)' enough? 'to find', 'to save'... are there any that are not like that? How about  with modals like 'I can see', the 'see', is that considered an infinitive?

Comment: @Mitch. That was my initial thought - then I re-read the question! It asks about "identifying the particular *role* of the infinitive in a sentence".

Comment: @TrevorD: Oh. Right. Then the OP should give examples of each part of speech (I can't think of an example of an infinitive as an adjective or adverb)

Comment: Relative infinitives modify nouns: _He's the man to do it, He's the man to see about it._ And there are infinitive embedded questions, where the infinitive modifies the _Wh_-word: _When to do it/How to get his attention is the problem_. If you want to call these infinitives adjectives and/or adverbs, go ahead. But I don't see where it helps anything; the Latin categories don't work in English.

Comment: There are articles at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive , http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/infinitive_function.php and http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/infinitive . And many grammarians would say that 'the to-infinitive is here behaving adverbially' is not identical to 'the to-infinitive is here an adverb'.

Comment: @TrevorD - I will be taking the GMAT exam shortly, and this is an area that I am particularly weak in.

Comment: @TrevorD : It is necessary to identify the role of Infinitives in order to get answers right for questions related to Parallelism and Verb Tense.

Comment: The first thing you need to consider is that different schools (eg those vaunted by the CGEL authors, Aarts, Quirk et al...) will give different explanations in various 'trickier' areas of English analysis. Your OP is a 'general English grammar' query, inviting different perhaps equally valid views from contributors, but now you are really switching the emphasis to 'which approach do the GMAT examiners want me to adopt?'

Comment: @darthy734 Thanks for the info. Have added your comments to the question. Sorry, can't help you further as this is beyond my knowledge! Bit note Edwin's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am somewhat weak in this subject also; however, I have developed a test that might work for your purposes also. It is to replace the infinite with a noun, an adjective, and an adverb, and see which one sounds best. For example:

Noun: "Half our life is spent trying to find something **hamburger** with the time we have rushed through life trying to save." - Will Rogers

Adverb: "Half our life is spent trying to find something **slowly** with the time we have rushed through life trying to save." - Will Rogers

Adjective: "Half our life is spent trying to find something **larger** with the time we have rushed through life trying to save." - Will Rogers

It appears to me that the role of "to do" is that of an *Adjective*.